# What is the correct preposition to be used with 'angle'?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, phrase-meaning

is any of these statements correct?

1. "so he ordered our soldiers to turn the frontline as to be positioned with an angle of 30⁰ from the enemy’s frontline and then move swiftly."
2. "so he ordered our soldiers to turn the frontline as to be positioned at an angle of 30⁰ with the enemy’s frontline and then move swiftly."
3. "so he ordered our soldiers to turn the frontline as to be positioned with an angle of 30⁰ to the enemy’s frontline and then move swiftly."

Thank you

Comment: I'd go for a combination of 2 and 3. "...at an angle of 30° to the enemy's front line".

Comment: Just because your example fragment starts with ***so*** (meaning ***therefore***) doesn't mean you don't need to include it *again* in the embedded adverbial clause: *so he ordered our soldiers to turn the frontline **so** as to be positioned **at** an angle of 30⁰ **to** the enemy’s front line...* (where it's a different meaning; ***so as to = in order to***).

Comment: "At an angle with" seems fine to me.